# Proving integral of a continuous function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, continuity, real-numbers

> Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be an open set, let $f : U \times [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Consider the function $$g(x):= \int_a^b f(x,y) \,dy$$
>   with $x \in U$.
>
> i) Prove that $g$ is continuous in $U$.
>
> ii) consider the function $f : [−1, 1] \times  [−1, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
>   $$f (x, y) :=\begin{cases} \frac {|y|−|x|} {y^2}&\text{ if $|x|<|y|$}\\
> 0 &\text{ if $|x|\geq |y|$}
> \end{cases}$$
>   Let $g(y):= \int_{-1}^1 f(x,y) \,dx$ for $y \in [-1,1]$
>   Study the continuity of $g$.

I know how to prove that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then $g=\int f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ but i assume because of the different notation and dimension here, i have to prove a different way? In addition, how would i study the continuity?